# Problem of existence of unused function in each screen when using SharedViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I have a question before I plan to use `SharedViewModel`.

`SharedViewModel` allows two screens to share(pass) data while using one `ViewModel`.

Assume that there are two fragments, `A` and `B`, using a `SharedViewModel` and having a `List type` of `LiveData`.

Fragment `A` can add and delete items from the List through the ViewModel. using `add()` and `delete()`.

In fragment `B`, there is `save()` that saves this List to `DB`.

By the way, although List data is shared through `SharedViewModel`, `save()` is not needed at all in `A`, and in `B`, there is no need for `add()` and `delete()` at all, and it is unused code.

Isn't this a problem at all?

Comment: "Isn't this a problem at all?" - strictly from an encapsulation point of view then yes.  How to avoid this - interfaces - SharedViewModel could implement 2 interfaces, which separate out required behaviour.  Then each fragment only needs to know about each interface, not the concrete class.  This way you have implemented Interface Segregation Principle and Dependency Inversion.  How the is supplied to each fragment .. DI or FragmentFactory etc.. are implementation details you'll need to figure out.

Comment: You still only write the code once if you only have one SharedViewModel class, so it's not really "unused"... The Fragment base class has all sorts of methods you probably aren't calling either, but that's not "unused code"

Comment: @Mark thanks

I'm sorry, but let me ask you a few questions.


**1.** i want to use the `MVVM pattern`, so i need a `Repository`. If so, can I have only one Repo like `SharedViewModel`? Or do I need repo for `A` and `B` respectively?

**2.** If i use a repo, how should you use the interface you said? If i use the interface in the `ViewModel` i know what to do, but if i use the `Repo`, how do i do it?